# scheme chicken regex logical grouping

Tags: chicken-scheme

have

```
(use extras format posix posix-extras regex regex-literals utils srfi-1)
```

have regex with logical groupings 1 and 2

```
/^(\\W+)\\s+(\\W+)/
```

but am having trouble with the syntax to actually -use- 1 and 2 .
Should I be using $1 $2 , or \1 and \2 , or something else? I'll be using
1 and 2 on the same LOC as the regex itself.

Thanks in advance,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 0):

This question is old and it isn't particularly clear: you don't explain how you've tried to use the regex.  I'll attempt to answer it anyway.

First off, there are no "special" variables `$1` or `$2` like in Perl or Ruby. With that out of the way, it becomes a simple matter of how to use the various procedures.

For example, with `string-match`, you simply receive a list of matches:

```
#;1> (use regex regex-literals)
#;2> (string-match  #/b(a)(r)/ "bar")
("bar" "a" "r")
```

So, to refer to the Nth submatch you'd use `(list-ref the-match N)` (where 0 equals the complete matched string).

With `string-substitute` and when using back references within the regex, you'd use `"\\1"` (you have to use two backslashes to escape the backslash in string context):

```
#;1> (use regex regex-literal)
#;2> (string-substitute #/f(o)(\1)/ "lala\\2xyz" "foo")
"lalaoxyz"
```

This works in general, but there's an undocumented feature (or perhaps a bug) that if you use a backslash in front of an escape sequence in the replacement, it will be escaped. See [this bugreport](http://bugs.call-cc.org/ticket/1189) on how that works, and how to use irregex instead of the regex egg to aovid this.